# Passing data between PHP and C executable in linux

Tags: php, c, linux, string, parameter-passing

Under Linux ,if I want to pass pure string from PHP to C, how do i do that?
what I've tried do far is:

```
exec("./myexec.bin -a mystring");
```

in PHP and

```
getopt(argc,argv, "a:");
```

in C

everything works, but when i pass strings longers than `MAX_ARG_STRLEN` (131072), it will no longer return 0 instead it returns 127 which is command not found....

is there any other ways to pass string data to a linux executable? or is there any way to overcome the `MAX_ARG_STRLEN` problem?

Comment: just to add, the string i'm passing might be longer than 393216 characters, because ((256^2)*6)*2; i thought of storing them in a file but then it's almost 1MB in size,  @Linus Kleen solution is currently my best solution so far

Comment: is it really only a string or is it a data-structure you want to pass?

Comment: after some experiments, i conclude that proc_open() is better since it provides both stdin and stdout whereas popen() provides only in or out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`popen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) to open a pipe to the executable:

```php
$fp = popen('./myexec.bin', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $data);
pclose($fp);
```

Then, as previously suggested, read from `stdin` in your C program:

```c
fopen(stdin, "r");
// ...
```

It is "safer" to use `popen()` rather than `exec('/bin/echo')` because you can write characters that would otherwise be interpreted by the shell (&, |, ...). Note that the handle returned from PHP's `popen()` **must** be closed with `pclose()`.

Answer (score 3):

A few options spring immediately to mind:

- Store the data in a file and pass the filename on the command line. It's easy and simple but does require permissions to create and store files somewhere on the filesystem.
- Open a pipe between your program and the C program; leave both processes running, at least until the C program has consumed the entire contents of your string. `popen()` is a convenient wrapper around this approach, but it does assume that standard input is the right destination, and it is *unidirectional*. Managing the pipes yourself lets you use a different file descriptor -- and you can tell the child which file descriptor to read via a command line argument. (See `gpg(1)`'s command line option `--passphrase-fd` to see what I mean.)
- Use a SysV or POSIX [shared memory segment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shm-put-var.php) to store you data in PHP, and then attach to the shared memory segment from your C program to read the contents. Note that shared memory segments *persist*, so you must clean up after them when you are done -- otherwise you will leak memory. This doesn't require permissions to create files in the filesystem and *might* be a nicer mechanism than dealing with pipes and keeping *both* processes alive long enough for one to completely write the data and the other to completely read the data.

Answer (score 1):

If it is more like a data structure than a string, what about using an embedded webserver? At first sight it may sound like overkill for your purpose, but mongoose for example is a very lightweight embeddable webserver:

http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/

There's also a nice tutorial about the exact same problem you have, transfering data between a PHP application and a C/C++ application. It's in german, though ... but maybe google translator can help:

http://blog.aditu.de/2010/05/15/serverbridge-zwischen-php-und-cc/

Answer (score 0):

<strike>try using `echo` and pipe the output to your `C` executable instead of using args:</strike>

`exec("/bin/echo  | ./myexec.bin");`

as [`@sarnold`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/377270/sarnold) mentioned in comments it's wrong. Look at [`@Linus Kleen`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/255756/linus-kleen) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193067/passing-data-between-php-and-c-executable-in-linux/8193128#8193128).

in your C program:

```
fopen(stdin, "r");
// ...
```

Comment: Your `echo` command has the exact same limitation on argument length.

Comment: @sarnold I thought limitation is because of the `C` program. Thanks for correction.

Comment: It's a kernel-enforced limitation -- the 128KB of today is in fact much larger than it used to be. :)